# How to add multiple $match conditions from different collections in MongoDB aggregates

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework, match

I have 2 different MongoDB collections - **Employees** and **Departments** containing both *deptid* in common. I want to join these 2 collections and add multiple $match conditions from both the collections.

Employees:

```
{
    Empid: 001
    Name: "John"
    Age: 41
    Location: "Belfast"
    deptid: "D101"
}
```

Dept:

```
{
    deptID: "D101"
    deptNM: "HR"
    deptPr: "O"
}
```

**Query:**

```
db.getCollection('Employees').aggregate([
    { $match:{
        deptNM: "HR",
        Age : {$gt: 40}
       }
    },
    { $lookup: {
        from: "Dept",
        localField: "deptid",
        foreignField: "deptID",
        as: "HR EMP"
        }
     },
     { $project: {
         Empid: 1, Name: 1, Location: 1, deptNM: 1, deptPr: 1
         }
     }
])
```

The above query isn't working, Is there any other way?

Comment: You can check my answer, it would work fine if an employee is related to single Dept i.e; ** HR_EMP** array has only one doc, if that's not the case if ** HR_EMP** array can contain multiple docs(A single doc in Employees matches with multiple docs in Dept) then let me know I'll tweak the query to work for that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You query has couple of issues - you can not filter on field `deptNM: "HR"` prior to `$lookup` stage as `deptNM` field is not from **Employees** collection, try below query :

```
db.getCollection('Employees').aggregate([
    /** filter employees to retain whose age > 40 */
    {
        $match: {
            Age: { $gt: 40 }
        }
    },
    /** Get their respective dept */
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Dept",
            localField: "deptid",
            foreignField: "deptID",
            as: "HR_EMP"
        }
    },
    /** As lookup's field HR_EMP is an array unwind it to get it into object */
    { $unwind: '$HR_EMP' },
    /** filter depts for HR */
    { $match: { 'HR_EMP.deptNM': "HR" } },
    /** Project only needed fields or transform fields */
    {
        $project: {
            Empid: 1, Name: 1, Location: 1, deptNM: '$HR_EMP.deptNM', deptPr: '$HR_EMP.deptPr'
        }
    }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_daBXlYPPzr)